# Ionic ng-submit ng-model returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, model, ionic-framework

I'm looking at one of the Ionic examples (http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html) for adding a new item. I'm using the form as they have it in the example:

```
<form ng-submit="createItem(item)">
  ...
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.title">
  ...
</form>
```

And I have a function that gets called by this form:

```
$scope.createItem = function (item) {
  console.debug('createItem', item);
  item.title = '';
};
```

Exactly like in the example.
Somehow this returns `createItem undefined` in the console.

I've checked whether there is something else in the example that I haven't added yet, but everything is there. The form is in a modal, the modal is being created and called in the main view's controller and while the `console.debug` runs, everything up to this point seems to be accurate.

Any ideas? It's probably something silly I'm missing...

UPDATE:

I'm not using a state because the form is in a modal (as in the example):

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-task.html', function(modal) {
  $scope.taskModal = modal;
}, {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
});
```

Comment: Can you show your routes and controller code?

Comment: How are you opening the modal? Do you have a controller for the modal? what is the scope option for the modal?

Comment: try to add '$scope.item = {};' in your controller.

Comment: Adding the item scope to the controller works, but why? And why isn't it in the example code from ionic themselves.